# How to basically encrypt text in an ELF binary?

Tags: c, encryption, elf

I've seen some binary files where the developer was a bit paranoid it seems and obfuscated all text in a binary. I hadn't seen anything like it before and didn't find any obvious options to compile an ELF with hidden text. Even standard OS API strings were hidden which was strange given they are usually visible.

These programs wouldn't exactly have any text that isn't exposed when it runs. Except unknown text. But hiding the whole lot just red flags and it makes it look suspicious.

Are there easy ways to hide text that is compiled into an ELF? Be that with easy compiler/linking options. I imagine a decoder could be inserted at main() but how could the text section be easily encoded?

I can imagine a custom way to do it would be to have an implicit decoder in the code with a key. Then use that key to encode text of the ELF. So that it is easily encoded.

Comment: What's your question? If all you're after is obfuscation, just XOR it using a fixed key... but then, what do you mean by "standard OS API strings"? The symbols imported from shared libraries? This would be strange indeed, only thing I can think of is indeed a custom loader first decrypting the whole file (like `upx` does for compression).

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an easy way it can be done. Regardless of obfuscation method. Say adding a switch to  compiler options that will hide text in the binary. I checked out the ELF format but nothing stood out in flags or anything that specified text as hidden. Which would then be decoded by the ELF loader.

And by "standard OS API strings" what I meant was names of libraries or solibs. Had a funny way of saying that one. :-)

Comment: No, there's no "easy" way, a feature like this wouldn't make much sense normally. Well, except -- seeing chqrlie's answer and re-reading my own comment -- `upx` (or similar tools) indeed! It doesn't encrypt anything, but of course, compressed text isn't directly readable as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

You must have been looking at compressed executable files.

There are various tools available to compress executable files and decompress them at load time, such as `upx` for linux.  Most text in the binary file will become unreadable to the naked eye , but be aware that it is a very ineffective method to hide sensitive data as hackers will have no difficulty decompressing the executable to gain access to the actual data.

Using encrypted strings in your executable, whose contents will have been produced by a script during the build process is a better approach, but the code to decrypt them must still be available somewhere in the executable, just harder to locate.  If the data is sufficiently valuable (database password, bitcoin keys...), hackers will get it.

Comment: I've wondered about this as well. Given all the code is all in one block. I ran readelf over it but no ELF compressed flags turned up. So it looks like a custom method was employed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by "text" you mean human readable text (and not the [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) a.k.a. text segment).

You could just encrypt or obfuscate it into a read only

```
const char encrypted_text[] = {
  // a lot of encrypted bytes like 0x01, 0x43, etc
  // the C file containing that would be generated by some script
};
```

Then you'll use your de-obfuscation or decryption routines to get the real (unciphered) text.

I'm not sure it is worth the trouble. Life is too short.

Comment: Yes I did mean  human readable text or strings as the computer calls them. :-)  I always thought that "text" section in binaries was confusing since it is only text at the source code level. And that it should be called "code". Well something was done to the code. Even if a decrypt() routine was inserted in a custom _start function or even at main() it would need to know where in memory the strings are. I don't know if it's possible to find where the string section is stored in memory. Except by knowing the first string and using that as a start address. Then there is the length.

Comment: Which could be decoded from reading the ELF binary itself. So assuming all the strings are concatenated in one block or section of the ELF this is possible. That, though getting complicated, would be the easy way to do it to me. Set up an early decrypt routine to decode all strings at one block with some key. Use said key with custom ELF encoder to hide strings. Like you said. Life is too short. But it was done some way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I've normally seen this when analyzing malware.  The authors do this to to prevent static analysis tools like `strings` from working.  Additionally, such authors might load functions by using `dlopen` and `dlsym` to get functions that they need.

For example, in the code snippet below;

```
printf("Hello World");
```

I would see the string "Hello World" in the output of `strings` and by looking at the import section of the elf file, I'd see that the program is making use of `printf`.  So without running the program it is possible to get a sense of what it is doing.

Now lets assume that the author wrote a function `char* decrypt(int)`.  This function take an index into a sting table (which each string is encrypted) and returns the decrypted string.  The above one line of code would now **notionally** look like

```
void* pfile = dlopen(decrypt(3));
void* pfunct = dlsym(pfile, decrypt(15));
pfunct(decrypt(5));
```

Again, remember that the above is closer to pseudo-code then actually compileable code.  Now in this case using static analysis tools we would not see the strings or the function names (in the import section).

Additionally, if we were attempting to reverse engineer the code we would need to take time to decrypt the strings and work through the logic to determine what functions are being called.  It's not that this can't be done but it will slow down that analyst, which means that it will be longer till a mitigation for the malware is created.

And now to your question;

> Are there easy ways to hide text that is compiled into an ELF? Be that
>   with easy compiler/linking options. I imagine a decoder could be
>   inserted at main() but how could the text section be easily encoded?

There is not compiler / linker option that does this.  The author of this would need to choose to do this, write the appropriate functions (i.e. decrypt) above and write a utility to produce the encrypted forms of the strings.  Additionally, as others have suggested once this is done, the entire application can be encryped/compressed (think of a self-extracting zip file) thus the only thing you see initially with static analysis tools would be the stub to decrypt of decompress the file.

see https://www.ioactive.com/pdfs/ZeusSpyEyeBankingTrojanAnalysis.pdf for an example of this.  (granted this is Windows based, but the techniques for encryption and dynamically loading functions is the same.  Look at section on API calls)

If interested you can also see; https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224180021_On_the_analysis_of_the_Zeus_botnet_crimeware_toolkit and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5569.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your extensive explanation of this. I doubt the code went to that trouble to hide what it was doing since the only things it is really hiding are certain libraries it opens. But I haven't seen the code run either. That is running through a debugger. I might just run it through GDB. Using a GUI would be best as I don't look forward to step by step debugging in ASM. :-)